# SQL dynamic query without EXEC

Tags: sql, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

What are the current alternatives for a query with dynamic filters?
For example:

```
SELECT cost
FROM tblData
WHERE Filter1 in (3,5,6,7)
AND Filter2 in (20,11,66,24)
AND Filter3 in (50,22,66,33)
```

and so on...
I may don't have Filter2, or Filter1, or Filter3 (depends on the parameters).
In my real scenario I can have up to 10 filters. Above was just an example.

Is there any new approach without building this query like text and executing with EXEC?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the potential columns on the left side of the predicates static?  In other words, you're not talking about 1 of 100 column names.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative by using `null` values.

For example:

```
WHERE (@filter Is Null OR table.column <> @filter)
  AND (@filter2 Is Null OR table.column2 <> @filter2)
```

However the performance may be affected if you filter on many columns. Look at [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 0):

dynamic generate sql through parameters,
then try to use  EXEC (@sql)

if you use sqlserver2005,
you can use EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, 
SP_EXECUTESQL more strong

Answer (score 0):

I have used filters in SQL Queries in the form of:

```
declare @filter1 as Int
declare @filter2 as Int
declare @filter3 as Int

set @filter1 = 39
set @filter2 = 84
set @filter3 = null

select *
from Table1 T1
     inner join Table2 T2 on T1.Id = T2.T1_Id
     inner join Table3 T3 on T2.Id = T3.T2_Id
where     T1.Id = isnull(@filter1, T1.Id)
      and T2.Id = isnull(@filter2, T2.Id)
      and T3.Id = isnull(@filter3, T3.Id)
```

But, if you have a lot of information, SQL Server wouldn't figure out the query in the correct way and it wouldn't use the correct indexes it has in the data base.

I would suggest to use a query in the form of:

```
declare @filter1 as int
declare @filter2 as int
declare @filter3 as int

set @filter1 = 39
set @filter2 = 84
set @filter3 = null

--Dynamic Query Begin
declare @query as varchar(max)

set @query = '
select *
from Table1 T1
     inner join Table2 T2 on T1.Id = T2.T1_Id
     inner join Table3 T3 on T2.Id = T3.T2_Id
where T1.Id = T1.Id '

if @filter1 is not null
    set @query = @query + ' and T1.Id = ' + convert(varchar(10),@filter1)

if @filter2 is not null
    set @query = @query + ' and T2.Id = ' + convert(varchar(10),@filter2)

if @filter3 is not null
    set @query = @query + ' and T3.Id = ' + convert(varchar(10),@filter3)

exec sp_executesql @query
--Dynamic Query End
```